# sharepoint web service set approver emails to approval workflow

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am developing `sharepoint 2010` and I would like to call approval workflow remotely.

I am doing it via web service with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow.startworkflow%28v=office.12%29.aspx  this method.

Everything is ok, workflow is running ,but every time it sends email to me, and I would like to specify people which send mails to. (**set approvers**)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did it with Jquery. You can do it similarly with C#:

http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2012/01/09/spworkflowapprovers.html

https://gist.github.com/madhur/1584225